# Where does this inequality come from? I don't see how is relevant.

Tags: metric-spaces

I understand it, but I don't know how I would find my way to it by myself, I've made some sketches to try to understand. But still i feel like missing something. Hope you understand me.
$|d(x,y)-d(z,t)|\leq d(x,z)+d(y,t)$

I understand that the distance between 2 of those points less another distance will be less than the sum of other 2 distances, feels like obvious that a substracion deals a number smaller than a sum

Comment: The relevancy of this inequality is the following: It shows that the metric $d$ is continuous as a function $d:\>X\times X\to{\mathbb R}_{\geq0}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose (without loss of generality) that $d(x,y)\geq d(z,t)$.  Then this inequality says $d(x,y)-d(z,t)\leq d(x,z)+d(y,t)$, or equivalently $$d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,t)+d(t,y).$$
But this is essentially just the triangle inequality (or perhaps more accurately, the "quadrilateral inequality"): it says that if you go from $x$ to $z$ to $t$ to $y$ and add up the distances of each step, this can't be smaller than the distance just going directly from $x$ to $y$.  You can formally prove this by using the triangle inequality twice: $$d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)\leq d(x,z)+(d(z,t)+d(t,y)).$$

Answer (score 2):

This is a double application of the triangle inequality.
$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,t)+d(t,y),$$
so
$$d(x,y)-d(z,t) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,t).$$
Similarly
$$d(z,t)-d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,t),$$
and the result follows. The proof should tell you how to sketch the situation convincingly; going directly from $x$ to $y$ is "faster" than going from $x$ to $z$, then from $z$ to $t$, then from $t$ to $y$.